# Split and pair substrings by condition

Tags: java, string, split, substring

I have a string like this: `"aa-bb,ccdd,eeff,gg-gg,cc-gg"`. I need to split the string by `'-'` signs and create two strings from it, but if the comma-delimited part of the original string doesn't contain `'-'`, some placeholder character needs to be used instead of substring. In case of above example output should be:

String 1:

```
"{aa,ccdd,eeff,gg,cc}"
```

String 2:

```
"{bb,0,0,gg,gg}"
```

I can't use the `lastIndexOf()` method because input is in one string. I am not sure how to much the parts.

```
if(rawIndication.contains("-")){
    String[] parts = rawIndication.split("-");
    String part1 = parts[0];
    String part2 = parts[1];
}
```

Comment: When you say "string" in your result, do you mean "array"?

Comment: @ggorlen : No input and output are strings.

Comment: OK, I added quotes on the example results to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    // First split the source String by comma to separate main parts
    String[] mainParts = sourceStr.split(",");

    for (String mainPart: mainParts) {
        // Check if each part contains '-' character
        if (mainPart.contains("-")) {
            // If contains '-', split and add the 2 parts to 2 arrays
            String[] subParts = mainPart.split("-");
            list1.add(subParts[0]);
            list2.add(subParts[1]);

        } else {
            // If does not contain '-', add complete part to 1st array and add placeholder to 2nd array
            list1.add(mainPart);
            list2.add("0");
        }
    }

    // Build the final Strings by joining String parts by commas and enclosing between parentheses
    String str1 = "{" + String.join(",", list1) + "}";
    String str2 = "{" + String.join(",", list2) + "}";

    System.out.println(str1);
    System.out.println(str2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Java 8 solution, using streams.  The logic is to first split the input string on comma, generating an array of terms.  Then, for each term, we split again on dash, retaining the first entry.  In the case of a term having no dashes, the entire string would just be retained.  Finally, we concatenate back into an output string.

```
String input = "aa-bb,ccdd,eeff,gg-gg,cc-gg";
int pos = 1;
String output = String.join(",", Arrays.stream(parts) 
    .map(e -> e.split("-").length >= (pos+1) ? e.split("-")[pos] : "0")
    .toArray(String[]::new));

System.out.println(output);
```

This outputs:

```
bb,0,0,gg,gg
```

Comment: This solution does not handle the scenario where the string segment does not contain "-". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56161913/2140633

Comment: @UdithGunaratna I fixed that edge case, thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

With the way you structured the problem, you should actually be splitting by commas first. Then, you should iterate through the result of the call to `split` and split each string in the outputted array by hyphen if there exists one. If there isn't a hyphen, then you can add a `0` to string 2 and the string itself to string 1. If there is a hyphen, then add the left side to string 1 and the right side to string 2. Here's one way you can do this,

```
if(rawIndication.contains(",")){
    String s1 = "{";
    String s2 = "{";
    String[] parts = rawIndication.split(",");
    for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if(parts[i].contains("-") {
            String[] moreParts = parts[i].split(",");
            s1 = s1 + moreParts[0] + ",";
            s2 = s2 + moreParts[1] + ",";
        }
        else{
            s1 = s1 + parts[i] + ",";
            s2 = "0,";
        }
    }
    s1 = s1.substring(0, s1.length() - 1); //remove last extra comma
    s2 = s2.substring(0, s2.length() - 1); //remove last extra comma
    s1 = s1 + "}";
    s2 = s2 + "}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this solves your problem.

```
private static void splitStrings() {
   List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aa-bb", "ccdd", "eeff", "gg-gg", "cc-gg");
    List firstPartList = new ArrayList<>();
    List secondPartList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String undividedString : list){
        if(undividedString.contains("-")){
            String[] dividedParts = undividedString.split("-");
            String firstPart = dividedParts[0];
            String secondPart = dividedParts[1];
            firstPartList.add(firstPart);
            secondPartList.add(secondPart);
        } else{
            firstPartList.add(undividedString);
            secondPartList.add("0");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(firstPartList);
    System.out.println(secondPartList);
}
```

**Output is -**

```
[aa, ccdd, eeff, gg, cc]
[bb, 0, 0, gg, gg]
```

Comment: Input is stored as a string, not list.